# DataGridView RowHeader number at the right corner

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to add row number in row header to `DataGridView` control, I found a code online and it works perfectly, but I'm using Arabic so my `DataGridview` control is **RightToLeft Layout**.

The code adds the numbers in the left corner **LeftToRight LayOut**.

How can I display the numbers in the RowHeader **RightToLeft Layout** ?

**My code**

```
Private Sub RGridView_RowPostPaint(ByVal sender As Object, 
ByVal e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles RGridview.RowPostPaint
Using b As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(RGridview.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor)
e.Graphics.DrawString(e.RowIndex.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture),
RGridview.DefaultCellStyle.Font, b, e.RowBounds.Location.X + 
20, e.RowBounds.Location.Y + 4)
End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set DataGridView property RightToLeft to True.
That way, you could change your event like that:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPostPaint

    Using b As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(DataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.RowIndex.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture),
                          DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font, b, e.ClipBounds.Width - 30, e.RowBounds.Location.Y + 4)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Obtaining the following result:
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: but how can i make it start from 1 not 0 ??
and thank you its working :)

Comment: It is sufficient to increase by 1 the RowIndex you're processing:
(e.RowIndex + 1).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
Let me know if its ok ;)